# OnSuccessListener is not called for every item in an ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I have an ArrayList of my Post class which contains all posts made by the user. The post class has a member variable which contains the path inside FireBase storage to the image for that post. I am trying to loop through the list, use that path to grab the download URL for each post, and add the images to a gridview with an adapter. However, not all URL's are grabbed. When testing it on my profile, the profile page only displays 4 posts, when I have actually made 7. Here is the code in question:

```
for (Post p : post_list)
                {
                    //Log.d("notebook", "loop");
                    storage.child(p.getPath()).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            urls.add(uri.toString());
                            GridAdapter gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(getActivity(), urls);
                            gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

The loop does loop 7 times as it should, but the listener is only called 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking a counter in your adapter setting code, so that your gridview is set once all the urls have been retrieved like this.

```
final int[] count = {1};

for (Post p : post_list)
            {
                //Log.d("notebook", "loop");
                storage.child(p.getPath()).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        urls.add(uri.toString());

                        count[0]++;

                        if(count[0] == post_list.size()) {
                           GridAdapter gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(getActivity(), urls);
                           gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: when I try that, the size of urls is zero, meaning it does not contain any URL's. I think this has to do with the asynchronous nature of the listener. Not sure how to fix this though.

Comment: You are right. I've updated the code. Perhaps this could work.

Comment: Still only grabs 4 URL's. I've now made a new post, so the total is 8. The size of post_list is 8. Still no idea why the listener seems to only be called 4 times.

Comment: Are you sure the listener is called only 4 times?

Comment: Yes i put a log statement inside the listener and only 4 images get displayed on the profile page.

Comment: Try making sure that all your `post_list` objects correctly map to the structure of your `Post.class`.

Comment: Just wanted to reply and say i figured out the problem. One of my team mates changed the way photos are uploaded so the every new post I made after their change was not receiving the download URL. They made this change after I had already made 4 posts, hence only 4 URL's being grabbed.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. The fact that 4 was always being returned was "telltale".